# Save prefered option of each user in Telegram bot python

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I wrote a telegram bot using telegram bot python API, I want to implement two button option for user to select but I don't have any database to save the option with chat_id.

For example: *A user want to translate a Eng text to another language, And has two languages available: 1.Persian 2.Spanish
user will select a language and then send the text and its choice will be saved for other texts*

Can anyone help me to do that? Personally I thought that I can initialize a python dictionary with chat_id and its option but this is not practical.
Recently, I heard something about conversion handler that added in alpha version of telegram bot API, can I use it in this situation?